# How to add Admin dashboard template to .Net Core 2 default application?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using VS2017 and I need to add a new template and I have no idea where to put CSS, JS and HTML files to remove the default template and insert my new dashboard template...HELP

Comment: The default template is _Layout.cshtml you have to include your css and js file to that file in order to use your template

Comment: Thanks but there is no _Layout.cshtml , as it was in MVC 5

Comment: There are two ways, 1) if your application is not so wide then you can add Content folder in that add images and css files and utilize.2) is the functionality is wide then you can have the separate media file in that add scripts, css and  images . then in project add the combres.xml and load the media files.[link](https://www.completecsharptutorial.com/mvc-articles/mvc-design-master-page-layout-with-css-html-template.php) hope this is usefull.

Comment: Thanks but I have chosen a Angular Template with .NET Core 2 application, I found few folders like wwwroot and Client , so do we need to initialize all files in these or the way u told me??